# Scale date-picker on mobile based on set margin

Tags: css, mobile, less, scale, margin

I need a set margin around two date-pickers. I need to scale the date-pickers horizontally according to the screen width. The dash should always be in the center of the container. I've tried solving it by using percentages, but I have no idea how to set the margins as well. Both date-pickers need to scan evenly and always be of equal size. Do anyone have an idea on how to solve this in a neat way?

[image: Scaled by margin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: flex` will work for this, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sxh0n7d1/5/

Hard to tell what you are asking but here is another approach https://jsfiddle.net/sxh0n7d1/6/

or this: https://jsfiddle.net/sxh0n7d1/7/

**Pick one, and I will explain how it was done.**

sample html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1">

  </div>
  <div class="line">

  </div>
  <div class="div2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Sample css

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: dotted;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.line {
  width: calc(100% - 320px);
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  margin: 0 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering with great examples. The problem with the examples is that the distance between the date-pickers changes; this needs to be constant. So, in practice, they need to scale inwards towards the center of the screen.

Comment: @Pelle it is easy to do, but could you better describe what it is you want? the width of the dates change, the space between them stays the same and the margin on the outside stays the same?

Comment: It was a bit difficult to explain. The last jsfiddle is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Pelle what made this work is the css `calc()` look at div1 and div2 css `width: calc(50% - 45px);` that both divs 45px smaller then 50% of the width always, to make it perfect though you would subtract the width of the borders too

Comment: yes, I noticed that. Didn't know you could do that, so this will get in handy on later occasions as well.

Comment: Actually, I tried this now when I got to work expecting it to work flawlessly, but unfortunately the div's refuses to fill the wrapper propperly, and I have no idea why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121910/discussion-between-pelle-and-adam-buchanan-smith).

Comment: I found the reason: I was writing "less" code that auto-generated the css, so that the result of the calc function got calculated before the code ran. I wrote this instead: width: ~"calc(50% - 45px)"; and it works.